# Update row entries using Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2014 database called `Database.Main` which has columns `Type` and `Code`.

I need to modify an existing Transact-SQL script to select all the rows that have `Type` equal to `MyObject.Main` and change the `Code` to integer 1000.

How can I do this in Transact-SQL?

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN Update_Table;

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  print 'Error encountered updating entries'
  print ERROR_MESSAGE()
  rollback;
END CATCH
```

**Answer**

Based on the answer from Raul below the solution is this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN Update_Table;
        UPDATE Database.Main
        SET Code = 1000
        WHERE Type = 'MyObject.Main';
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  print 'Error encountered updating entries'
  print ERROR_MESSAGE()
  rollback;
END CATCH
```

Comment: How would you do it in SQL? Where is your update statement?

Comment: Where is the existing SQL statement? We may need it to check whats the issue with your existing script.

Comment: You don't need a transaction for a singe statement.  A single statement is a transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `UPDATE` command would do?

```
update table_name
set Code = 1000
where Type = 'MyObject.Main';
```

Comment: maybe add and Code <> 1000

Comment: @Paparazzi, per OP the only condition is on `Type` column and per OP's updated post looks he is good on that but still a valid point and Thanks for pointing that.